# javascript regex not cointains word in middle

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I want to check regex not contains word in middle.
my regex code below

```
/con\/.+\/top/.test("con/bottom/pop/down/top")
```

in this regex first and last will be "con" and "top", in between .+ it should not match /pop/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lookahead after each slash:

```js
const re = /con\/((?!pop\/)[^\/]+\/)+top/;
console.log(re.test("con/bottom/pop/down/top"))
console.log(re.test("con/bottom/popo/down/top"))
console.log(re.test("con/bottom/top"))
console.log(re.test("con/pop/top"))
console.log(re.test("con/popo/top"))
```